# Как после отправки содержимого <textarea> сохранить этот текст в самом теге, а обработчику передать текст со всеми символами перехода?

Tags: php, html

Хочу сделать небольшой обработчик текста. Я использую `<textarea>` для вставки текста из буфера и небольшой корректировки вручную. Текст этот, как правило, многострочный и, возможно, в дальнейшем его придется построчно обрабатывать функцией file. После отправки надо, чтобы текст не пропадал из тега (чтобы был перед глазами). Кроме того, $_POST['textarea'] становится одной строкой при отправке, можно ли привести к тому виду, какой был в теге (со символами перехода с новой строки). Как все это сделать?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <p><textarea autofocus id="textarea1" style="width:50%; height:50%" name="textarea" value="<?php echo $_POST['textarea'];?>"></textarea></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить!"</p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php 
    echo $_POST['textarea'];
?>
```

Comment: Насчет value="$_POST["textarea"]" я что-то затупил... Конкатенацией надо сделать.

Comment: value="$_POST["textarea"]" - нельзя так делать, сломают Ваш проект :) посмотрите в сторону безопасности.

Comment: @forever_young у тега `textarea` нет атрибута `value`. Если надо сделать вывод в текстовой области, то вставляйте данные между тегов `<textarea>тут данные</textarea>` Для перевода строк юзайте `nl2br()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение тега textarea выводится не в value, а между тегами. Обязательно нужно экранировать.

```
$value = isset($_POST['field_name']) ? $_POST['field_name'] : '';
<textarea><?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Точно! C input перепутал. Спасибо!  Что значит htmlspecialchars? Почему не echo?

Comment: <?=  - это краткая запись <?php echo

htmlspecialchars экранирует строку. 

Введите в поле "</textarea><script>alert('xss')</script><textarea>" и все поймете.